# Could service port be the same in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes, I have an application pod (A-pod), then I create a service (A-service) for this pod and expose service's port as 5678.

Now in a cluster, I have 5 namespaces, each namespace will running a service (A-service) and a pod (A-pod), so in  total there are 5 A-services that are running.

My question is, because 5 A-services is using the same port (5678), does it cause conflict? How to access the different services in different namespace with service name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it assigns each different Service name in each namespace. If you have a `Service` called `A-service` in a Kubernetes namespace `your-ns`, the control plane and the DNS Service acting together create a DNS record for `A-service.your-ns` appropriately. Refer [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns) for more details.